# Accessing the CakeEmail subject from a template/layout

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1, cakeemail

I'm using [CakeEmail](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-CakeEmail.html) as follows:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->template('my_template', 'my_layout');
$Email->subject('My Subject');
// ...
```

How do I access the 'My Subject' value in `my_layout.ctp`?

The closest thing I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535979/cakephp-2-html-helper-in-email-template) but it's not very relevant. I'm looking at the [`CakeEmail::_renderTemplates()` source code](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/source-class-CakeEmail.html#1421) and it doesn't seem to do that but I'm not sure.

I know I can also pass the subject line to `$Email->viewVars` but that's not very flexible. Please advise!

Comment: An option I didn't think about when I asked the question: create your own wrapper around `CakeEmail` with all the necessary functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than setting a View variable there is no way of doing this with `CakeEmail`. However, you could extend `CakeEmail` so that the email's subject is added to the available variables in your template.

I haven't tested this, but you should be able to do something like this:-

```
// app/Lib/CustomCakeEmail.php

App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

class CustomCakeEmail extends CakeEmail {

    protected function _renderTemplates($content) {
        if (!empty($this->_subject) && empty($this->_viewVars['subject'])) {
            $this->_viewVars['subject'] = $this->_subject;
        }
        return parent::_renderTemplates($content);
    }

}
```

Here `CakeEmail::_renderTemplates()` is extended to set the subject in the view variables (as long as it hasn't already been set elsewhere). You'd then use the extended class instead of `CakeEmail` like this:-

```
App::uses('CustomEmail', 'Lib');

$Email = new CustomCakeEmail();
$Email->template('my_template', 'my_layout');
$Email->subject('My Subject');
```

Your View template would have a `$subject` variable containing the email's subject.

Comment: Didn't try this, but I'm accepting the answer because it will be helpful to whoever tries to. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There's no other way besides setting the subject to a view var too.

Comment: Upvoted. Just make the subject a variable and use it with the subject and as template var. The other answer works as well, but do you seriously want all that code plus overloading a class just to archive *that*?